# Reading single backslash from a text file using java code

Tags: java, escaping

There are lot of post on this, and everyone suggesting to change the text file content. 
My requirement here is, i am parsing a c++ source file. During this parsing i might need to merge multi lines together when i find a backslash at the end. 
Example:
char line[100]="hello join the multiple lines.\
                            Oh, dont ask me to edit CPP source file.";

How do I read this text from xyz.cpp file, and figure out the line has a backslash at the end.
I used FileInputReader to read line by line, but the backslash is missing when i get the line in java.

I hope you will not suggest me to change my CPP source code to replace \ with \

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have an example of a file with this backslash and what the output is when you try to read the file?

Comment: No you shouldn't miss  the backslash. The string should contain the backslash at the end. An example input will show your exact issue.

Comment: how you are parsing the file show us the sample code. Also how you are parsing?

Comment: There is no problem reading a backslash - it is just another character. What code do you have that makes you think the backslash is missing?

Comment: Using bufferreader.readLine()

Comment: Probably it is file format issue, utf or ANSI. I will look into that aspect as well. I will update tomorrow, its late night here. Thanks for all the input.good night.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is an escape character in Java. So if you want to match with a real backslash - `\`, then you have to look for `\\`.

You can use `contains()` or `indexOf()` for string literals.

Or read character by character and check the condition:

`if (c == '\\')`

Hope this helps!

Comment: It will be compilation error when we add single backslash in java code.Definitely i am comparing with\\.

Comment: @Bidya, fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

On the simplest level you can just split the file data by newlines (`data.split('\n')` where `data` is a `String`) and then check if it ends in a backslash (`line.endsWith('\\')` where `line` is a `String`)

Comment: I am reading line by line using Buffered Reader. And checking endsWith("\\"). Even in debug mode, the line returned by buffered reader do not have \ in it.

Comment: @Bidya in that case, can you try `line.trim().endsWith('\\')`? It might be leaving stray newlines or carriage returns at the end of the line, after the backslash. This will trim them out before checking.

Answer (score 0):

The following code loads the file and prints each line

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {


public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
    scan.useDelimiter("\\Z");
    String content = scan.next();
    String[] lines = content.split("\n");
    for (String value : lines) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
}
```

I created a file "file.txt" containing the following lines

```
line 1
line 2\
line 2cnt
line 3
```

The code will output

```
line 1
line 2\
line 2cnt
line 3
```

To join the lines you can run the following code

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
    scan.useDelimiter("\\Z");
    String content = scan.next();
    String[] lines = content.split("\n");

    for (String value : lines) {
        if (value.endsWith("\\")) {
            value = value.substring(0, value.length()-1);
            System.out.print(value);
        } else {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

which will output

```
line 1
line 2line 2cnt
line 3
```

Edited as per your comment:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

outputs

```
line 1
line 2\
line 2cnt
line 3
```

and

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.endsWith("\\")) {
            line= line.substring(0, line.length()-1);
            System.out.print(line);
        } else {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

outputs

```
line 1
line 2line 2cnt
line 3
```

Not sure, why you don't see the backslash on your machine. Can you post the complete code and the file content? What platform are you running it on? What is the encodeing of the file? Maybe you need to pass the encoding to the InputStreamReader like this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: May be this will help, i will try this, thanks. But i still have confusion on bufferreader.readLine(), is it eating backslash.

Answer (score 0):

It was compilation issue of eclipse ide, i restarted the eclipse and did clean compile. Now every thing is working as expected. Thank you guys for your time.